# Android Open Framework in Windows7

Tags: android, c++, windows, openframeworks

I have followed all the instructions mentioned in the following link to setup the Openframeworks for android in windows environment. While building the openFrameworks. I get the following error. Tried everything possible to work with but still not getting it correct. Mentioned the error as follows, please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Build of configuration Android for project openFrameworks **

make android -C../openFrameworksCompiled/project/android 
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - *.cpp
make: Entering directory `/c/Development/OF/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android'
make DebugAndroid
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - *.cpp
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - *.cpp
make[1]: Entering directory`/c/Development/OF/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `DebugAndroid'.
make[1]: Leaving directory`/c/Development/OF/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android'
make ReleaseAndroid
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - *.cpp
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - *.cpp
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Development/OF/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for`ReleaseAndroid'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Development/OF/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android'
make Release_arm7Android
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - *.cpp
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - *.cpp
make[1]: Entering directory`/c/Development/OF/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `Release_arm7Android'.
make[1]: Leaving directory`/c/Development/OF/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android'
make Release_neonAndroid
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - *.cpp
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - *.cpp
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Development/OF/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for`Release_neonAndroid'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Development/OF/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android'
make: Leaving directory`/c/Development/OF/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/android'

Build Finished **

Comment: Forgot to mention the link :
http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-setup-openframeworks-for-android-on-windows/